# Browser cache is breaking my Client Side router

Tags: javascript, html, url, browser

I'm developing a web app, and I use client-side routing (basically, we're loading the page using what's after the `#` in the URL).

But, I've noticed that **sometimes** when I go one page and I go on another one, the old one is loading instead of the new one. Let me explain when I click on the link to go wherever I want, the page I was on is loading.

I highly suspect that the browser cache is "overwriting" the new content.

> And I still don't know why it only happens sometimes (especially when it's a new browser window).

Are there any solutions to force the browser to open the new page, like opening the page in another page, and closing the old tab?

**EDIT**

I'm currently using GitHub pages to host my project, so in your answer, make sure that everything is client side .

Comment: How exactly are you loading new content? If you follow a link that has the same URL just differnet anchor the page would not reload.

Comment: @Matus Well, I have a page that acts as a menu, and these links are all pointing to a URL like `/foo/bar#something`.

Comment: Also, to make sure it is cache problem you can use dev tools  to disable cache and see if it fix the problem (just to be sure you are trying to solve the real problem)

Comment: I understand that but going from /foo/bar#something to /foo/bar#somethingElse would not load the page so how exaclty are you loading a new content ? (some code would help)

Comment: @Matus I tried to disable the cache, and it fixed my problem. I can provide the URL if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: open my link in a new tab, while closing the old one.

This can be done using the following code:

```
el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(el.href, "_blank")
    window.close()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following header from your server on all requests:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This would disable caching for that file/response. If you're using a expressJS server, you can set it as:

```
function nocache(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next();
}
```

And use this function as a middleware for all the routes you want to disable caching for.

You can read more about cache headers on [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently using GitHub pages to host my project (so I don't have the control of the headers)

Comment: It's not possible to do this there. But the cache expiry they've set is 600 sec. Either force reload every time or wait for 10 mins. You can move to a different hosting service maybe?

Comment: I just have a question, will the event "DOMContentLoaded" will still fire up if the page is in the cache? Cause I can force to reload the content if it fires up.

Comment: Even if you force reload, it'll still reload from the cache. This is a server-side thing. If you send a GET request for the same page with the same headers, doesn't matter if its sent using JS, it'll say that the copy you have locally is still fresh and you can use that. Your browser will then proceed to render that.

Comment: No, if it fires up and if I can get the correct content after hash, then it will work. (At least in that case)

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't depend on whether its a cached page you're loading or a  fresh one. It'll always be called on initial page load. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Though there is another thing you could do. Change the file name every time you make an edit. Especially if its a JS file. Change it at all places where its being used. The browser will now look for the new file and cache wont matter anymore.